# Save to PDF based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop the following project : I have a selection of sheets and inside of this selection I want to save to one pdf only the ones that have the cell C8 or C9 filled.
I managed to make it save only my selection but I'm not being able to add this filter to save only the ones with this cells filled.

Can you help me?
This is my code until now:

```
Sub Export_As_PDF()
Dim cx As Variant
Filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
 fileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
 If TypeName(Filename) = "Boolean" Then
MsgBox "Processo Cancelado."
Exit Sub
Else
CheckName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(Filename)
 If CheckName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
    C = Sheets(Array("Capa", "Aprovação","Receita","Anos")).Select
      For Each cx In C
        cx = Sheet(cx).Select
        If Not IsEmpty("C8") Or Not IsEmpty("D9") Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Filename, openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        MsgBox "Proposta Comercial Exportada para PDF."
        Else
        End If
      Next cx
  Else
    answer = MsgBox("The FileName already exists. Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
     If answer = vbYes Then
        C = Sheets(Array("Capa", "Aprovação","Receita","Anos")).Select
        For Each cx In C
        If Not IsEmpty("C8") Or Not IsEmpty("D9") Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Filename, openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        MsgBox "Proposta Comercial Exportada para PDF."
        Else
        End If
        Next cx
      Else
        MsgBox "Proposta Cancelada."
        Exit Sub
      End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, let alone work. The first thing you should do is put **Option Explicit** at the top of the module, then declare all your variables. Then Line 19 **cx = Sheet(cx).Select** need to read **cx = Sheets(cx).Select**. This is still wrong but at least it will compile. Keep hitting "Debug/Compile" from the main menu until the code compiles without error. The maybe we can help you fix the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try never to repeat the same code. I removed the repetitions so it is easier to maintain.

The idea here is  that you loop through all possible sheets, check the data in each sheet and collect the names of the sheet you actually want to export. Then only select those sheets and export them.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportAsPDF()
    Dim SaveToFilename As Variant
    SaveToFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
    If VarType(SaveToFilename) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Processo Cancelado."
        Exit Sub
    End If  ' no else needed as you exit anyway if it is true
    
    ' check if file exists and ask for overwrite
    Dim CheckName As String
    CheckName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(SaveToFilename)
    If Not CheckName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        Dim Answer As Long
        Answer = MsgBox("The FileName already exists. Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
        If Not Answer = vbYes Then
            MsgBox "Proposta Cancelada."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    
    On Error GoTo SHEET_NOT_FOUND ' if one of the sheets does not exist error
    Dim PossibleSheets As Sheets
    Set PossibleSheets = Sheets(Array("Capa", "Aprovação", "Receita", "Anos"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    Dim ExportSheetNames As Collection
    Set ExportSheetNames = New Collection
    
    ' Check if data exists and collect all sheet names with data
    Dim Sheet As Variant
    For Each Sheet In PossibleSheets
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet.Range("C8")) Or Not IsEmpty(Sheet.Range("D9")) Then
            ExportSheetNames.Add Sheet.Name, Sheet.Name
        End If
    Next Sheet
    
    ' Convert collection into array beacause Sheets() needs an array
    Dim ExportSheets() As String
    ReDim ExportSheets(0 To ExportSheetNames.Count - 1) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ExportSheetNames.Count - 1
        ExportSheets(i) = ExportSheetNames.Item(i + 1)
    Next i
    
    ' Export
    Sheets(ExportSheets).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SaveToFilename, openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
    
    MsgBox "Proposta Comercial Exportada para PDF."
    
    ' Error handling
    Exit Sub
SHEET_NOT_FOUND:
    MsgBox "One sheet was not found."
End Sub
```